# Form Submit Confirmation With SweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, sweetalert2

I'm working on a project that needs confirmation before submit the form, to do that I'm using SweetAlert2 but it doesn't work in any way. I tried with the code from another threads but I have the same issue, the page loads and when I submit the form, it doesn't do anything (well, it submits the information without verifications or questions). It works already like a beta version without the SweetAlert.

The HTML Form is something like this:

```
´<form class="form-register col-8" method="post" action="insert.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name="subjects"> 
  <option disabled="disabled">Select</option>
  <--!Here I have PHP code to list things from DB -->
</select>
<input id="m" type="text"/>
<select name="tempo">
  <option disabled="disabled">Select<option> <!--Regular options list-->
<select>
<input id="c" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" id="btn-ok" value="OK" name="register" class="btn btn-primary accept"/>
</form>´
```

My functional script without SweetAlert:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".form-register").submit(function(){
 if ($("#m").val().length<9){
  alertify.warning('Incomplete ID');
  return false;
 }
 if ($("#m").val().length>9){
  alertify.warning('Error');
  return false;
 }
 if ($("#c").val().length>200){
  alertify.warning('Write less comments please');
  return false;
 }
 else
 {
    var Con= confirm("Click ok if you are sure");
    if(Con == true)
    {
      return true;
    }
    {
      return false;
    }
 }
});
```

});

Note: I'm using the SweetAlert2 8.X from jsdelivr.
I tried to separate this script in a function and including it in the else (works at 50%, even if I quit the first two $ functions):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.form-register').submit(function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
    customClass: {
      confirmButton: 'btn btn-success',
      cancelButton: 'btn btn-danger'
    },
    buttonsStyling: false,
  })
  swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
    title: 'Are you  sure?',
    text: "Check plz",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'OK',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
    reverseButtons: true
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
      swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
        'Finished',
        'Success',
        'success',
      ), function(submit){
        form.submit();
        }
    } else if (
      result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
    ) {
      swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
        'Canceled',
        'Do corrections and then retry :)',
        'error'
      )
    }
  })
});
```

});

I tried to replace the submit type in the input with a button, and another selectors in the head of the script. The only thing I need is a confirmation to proceed with the insert of data on insert.php, and if the user cancel return another message of error if it's possible... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
<input type="submit" id="btn-ok" value="OK" name="register" class="btn btn-primary accept"/>
```

To:

```
<input type="button" id="btn-ok" value="OK" name="register" class="btn btn-primary accept"/>
```

Then, in your JS, listen for the click on "#btn-ok", then just programmatically submit the form using $form.submit(). See below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form #btn-ok').click(function(e) {
        let $form = $(this).closest('form');

        const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
            customClass: {
                confirmButton: 'btn btn-success',
                cancelButton: 'btn btn-danger'
            },
            buttonsStyling: false,
        })

        swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire({
            title: 'Are you  sure?',
            text: "Check plz",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'OK',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
            reverseButtons: true
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
                        'Finished',
                        'Success',
                        'success',
                    );                     
                $form.submit();
            } else if (
                result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
            ) {
                swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
                    'Canceled',
                    'Do corrections and then retry :)',
                    'error'
                );
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much... It's almost working at 100% but now I don't know why the form isn't submitted to the page insert.php, I only get the message with SWA2 and then it doesn't redirect or load the PHP code. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Only TypeError: g is undefined, but it's an error of bootstrap. Not related to the action of the form

Comment: I modified my answer. Can you try it?